# Large Number E OBIEE Report

Tags: oracle, reporting, number-formatting, obiee, bi-publisher

When I'm trying to view the data in the Data model it appears prefectly fine.

```
589062382

12075132
```

https://ibb.co/TLrDWgS

But when I try to view the Report a large number data 'E' appears in the report.

```
5.89062382E8
1.207513E2
```

https://ibb.co/ZmDWJvV

How to avoid that?

Below are the steps that I have used to create the report.

```
Datamodel -> Create Report ->

Select Data 
        Create Report Using Existing data model
        Guide Me
Select Layout
            Potrait
            Table
Create Table
                Drag and Dropped Columns
Save Report
```

Comment: Example images are not showing. Can you you show what the XML Element looks like, and what the RTF selection log is? Is this in Excel output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `TO_CHAR` to convert the number to a string, the entire number will be displayed. You can even format it with commas and such if you so desire.

#### Example Query

```
WITH n AS (SELECT 123456789123456789 AS num FROM DUAL)
SELECT num                                                AS with_e,
       TO_CHAR (num)                                      AS as_string,
       TO_CHAR (num, 'FM$999,999,999,999,999,999.00')     AS formatted_string
  FROM n;
```

#### Example Results

```
               WITH_E             AS_STRING               FORMATTED_STRING
_____________________ _____________________ ______________________________
  1.23456789123457E17 123456789123456789    $123,456,789,123,456,789.00
```